# Django, Jenkins and PyLint looking at everything

Tags: python, django, jenkins, pylint

I am currently running Jenkins CI with pylint to look at a Django project I've been working on. One thing I have been frustrated by is pylint reporting for all the central django modules I import, meaning that my own project files get buried within mounds of other django modules (e.g. /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py, which gives 67 violations alone).

Is there a way to make it less indiscriminate and just look at the files related to my project, or does it always have to recurse through all imports?

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right, well thanks to the creator of Django_Jenkins ([kmmbvnr](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/)) the correct way to get it to look at only your project's files is to use the following:

In settings.py, you need:

```
PROJECT_APPS=(
    'appname',
)
```

And that sorts out the searching through every dependency out there.

Hope that helps!

J

Comment: Another thing that helps a *lot* is using the django-jenkins options for specifying a custom pylintrc file.  The option is "--pylint-rcfile=<path_to_pylintrc>"  I have a custom pylintrc checked into my source repository that will ignore things I don't care about.

Answer (score 0):

From [pylint's docs](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#command-line-options):

> **Command line options**
>
> ...
>
> **--ignore=file**
>
> > Add  (may be a directory) to the black list. It
> >     should be a base name, not a path. You
> >     may set this option multiple times.

so:

```
pylint . --ignore=django
```

would probably solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unfortunately, I don't appear to be able to get the Django Jenkins integration to take --ignore arguments I have tried setting ignore=django in the pylint.rc of the django_jenkins install, however that doesn't appear to be recognised either...

Comment: What is your pylint command line?  Do you have a copy of django in your source tree?

Comment: Thanks for the help, managed to find the creator of django_jenkins and enquire with him, see above answer for how to.

Comment: A better option than this is to specify a custom pylintrc file for django-jenkins via the --pylint-rcfile option.